# how to run userscript after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am writing a GreaseMonkey script that needs to change HTML code in the page.
The page is modifying himself after AJAX request.
How can i run code when page modified?
Is there any event of adding / modifying element in page?

thank you.

Comment: Ajax has a call back method, you can do what ever you want in that method. Paste your code here so we can see and suggest you

Comment: I am not calling the Ajax request. The page does it. I am writing an Userscript for this page. Is there any event that running when an element added \ changed ?

Comment: Hoe the page does it?

Comment: there is a function called `ajaxHandlerCall` that sending an Ajax request and modifying the page.

Comment: Please read its documentation, you may get a call back method which you can use after ajax complete.

Comment: I am not calling the `ajaxHandlerCall` function. The page himself does it, so i can't provide callback method.

Comment: One idea could be just use `setInterval` to check every few seconds, if the change in the HTML has happend.

Comment: @RoToRa it's not so elegant way. Is there any way to set callback function for DOM element change?

Comment: is [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) what you need? You may also modify the `ajaxHandlerCall` via `unsafeWindow`, but pay attention to sandbox issues.

Comment: You can use Brock's waitForKeyElements function (https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891)